# Trying to upload multiple data using JSON - jQuery. Why not working?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am developing a web application using jquery-1.5.2.js . The server to which I am trying to upload is JSON formatted. I am trying to upload four variables to the server but I get an error. My code is as follows:

--Updated code using the suggestions below, still not working though:

```
image= JSON.stringify(imageEncode, replacer);
name = JSON.stringify(name, replacer);
id = JSON.stringify(id, replacer);
comments = JSON.stringify(comments, replacer);

function data_post(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: "example/new.json",
    data: "{'image': '" + image + "', 'name': '" + name + "', 'id': '" + id + "', 'comments': '" + comments + "'}",
    success: function () {
        alert('Successfully uploaded');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error on upload');
    }
});}
```

Why do I still get an "Error on upload" message?

Comment: @mu the error returns a textStatus: "error thrown" and textStatus: "Not Found". This is feedback by the app not quite helpful.

Comment: Actually that is helpful, you're getting a 404 from the server because it doesn't know what to do with `example/new.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is "Not Found". That means that you have no handler for `example/new.json` set up on your server. You need to configure your server software to know what to do with a URL like `example/new.json`, you should also consider using an absolute path for the `url` option so that you don't have to care where you are when the JavaScript is run, something like `/example/new.json` would serve you better.

Furthermore, the `data` option to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) can be a simple object:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { image: image_data, comments: comments, //...
    //...
});
```

There is no need to JSON encode it yourself, let jQuery deal with that.

Comment: So you are suggesting that there is no need to use the stringify method? Actually about the server, is a URL given to me by the server's developer and I need to access it by my application. I looks like (but is not that):  http://theURL.com/people/1/photo/new

Comment: @tasanoui: Usually you don't need to stringify the data yourself but that's just an aside. Your real problem is that the `url` should be `'/people/1/photo/new'` (or possibly `'/people/1/photo/new.json'` depending on your server software and how it is set up).

Comment: Yes, you are right the real problem is the URL, which should be as you suggested. But even though I am now able to successfully upload something, if I move to the server's page nothing is really there!

Comment: @tasanoui: Talk to the person that gave you that URL, I don't know what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a server error but one thign I can suggest from thiscodeis make sure your data is stringified. `base64EncodeImage` is one suspect, but check others too. You need to send valid JSON. Are you receiveing anything on the server?

Comment: I am not receiving anything on the server unfortunately. How can I do my data stringified?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "data" json. The code you provided works, if you will use this:

```
data: "{'image': '" + base64EncodeImage + "','name': '" + photoName "',...
```